# reading state of redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

Could someone explain why I am able to read user.token_type but its undefined if trying to read user.user.id

```
  const user = useSelector(
    (state) => state.userreducer.user.token_type /* WERT AUS REDUX DB*/
  );
```

Output: bearer

```
  const user = useSelector(
    (state) => state.userreducer.user.user.id /* WERT AUS REDUX DB*/
  );
```

Output: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

[image]

Comment: Can you print the `state` and debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read your issues and I understood the reason.
Although the redux loads `user` data when your app is rendered, it will take some time.
So `user` is null in initial state.
Finally `token_type` property of `null`(user) can't be accessed.

In order to solve this problem, you need to use this code.

```js
  const user = useSelector(
    (state) => state.userreducer?.user?.token_type
  );

const user = useSelector(
    (state) => state.userreducer?.user?.user?.id
  );
```

Thank you for reading my advice.